# Viewing TypeScript --noEmit output in Node.js inspector

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to see TypeScript linting warning reports while editing files in a Node.js inspector workspace (Chrome dev tools), but running `node --inspect ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --noEmit --watch` still only shows the output in the terminal, not through the inspector's console. The file paths could help me go to the warning locations on click and I wouldn't have to keep two windows open. I tried looking inside tsc but I didn't see anything that would redirect output from stdout, only regular `console.log`s. What might be the reason for this, where the code evades stdout so i can at least patch it, or how could it be fixed?
[image: empty inspector log]